# Solving a system of two cubic equations $\begin{cases}2x-yx^2-y^3 = 0\\ 2y-xy^2-x^3 = 0 \end{cases}$

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

I am trying to solve this system of two cubic equations
$$\begin{cases}2x-yx^2-y^3 = 0\\ 2y-xy^2-x^3 = 0 \end{cases}$$
Is there a good way of attacking this in order to be sure to find ALL possible solutions? It is trivial to see that (0,0) and (1,1) are solutions, but I am at a loss trying to find other solutions.

Is a correct conclusion that since $x$ and $y$ have the same "role" in both equations that all solutions should be on the $y=x$ line? Or is there more to it?

Comment: In the real domain,  $(-1,-1)$ is also a solution. In the complex domain $(-i,i)$ and $(i,-i)$ are other solutions; these last two are not on the $y=x$ line.

Comment: Your conclusion that all solutions should lie on the line $y=x$ is not correct. A simple counterexample is furnished by the equation $xy = 0$. This is also symmetric in $x$ and $y$ but surely there are more solutions than the ones where $x=y$. However, it is true that if $x=a, y=b$ is a solution, then the same is true of $x=b, y=a$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subtract the second one from the first. You get $2(x-y)-xy(x-y)+x^{3}-y^{3}=0$. If $x \neq y$ you can divide by $x-y$ and simplify to get $2+x^{2}+y^{2}=0$. There are no real numbers satisfying this (becasue the left side is $>0$). Hence we must have $x=y$ and now it is very easy to find all solutions.

[Apart from you solutions you get just one more solution: $(-1,-1)$].

Comment: Nice solution, could you tell me more how you chose the operations you did? It looks really neat, and any pointers in how I can learn to come up with something similiar myself would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just one observation made it all simple. I realized that when  you subtract one from the other all the terms are divisible by $x-y$ which helps us  reduce the  degree of the polynomials from $3$ to $2$. But then  I ended up with a second degree equation with no solution! @JonLachmann